# Enable/Disbale Tableview cell - iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view loaded with 4 rows inside.

Row 3 will have a checkbox. I want to enable Row 4 only when Row3 check box is checked

so I have an outlet for checkbox (which is button) and action on tap of that checkBox.

My question is how can i get reference to next cell and make it enable/diable

I tried to get reference of that cell as 
`myTableView.cellForRow(at: index + 1)` but it throws error that Binary operand cannot be applied to indexPath.

Pls suggest how i can achieve

Comment: Please post this your code so we can help...

Comment: There are two parts to an `IndexPath`: a `row` and a `section`. You need to check that your `indexPath.row` is valid. Here's a method that would enable you do that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40665778/4475605

Comment: Simple way - create 4 UITableViewCell instances, put them in array and in cellForRow do not call dequeue method, just return corresponding cell.

Comment: what do you mean by enable/disable

Do You want to show cell in both cases but in the disabled cell user should not be able to interact with that cell?

Comment: @ashh check new answer below

Comment: try myTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: index+1, section: 0))

Comment: Did my answer worked for you??

Comment: post by @rv7284..below check worked if let secondCell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: (index + 1), section: 0)) as? MyCustomCell { --Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking on checkBox let's say have a method name **checkBoxClicked**.
You can do like following:

```
@IBAction func checkBoxClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let button = sender as! UIButton
        let clickedIndex = button.tag

        let nextIndexPath = IndexPath(item: clickedIndex+1, section: 0) // specify section here, if it's sectioned tableview
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: nextIndexPath)

        // enable cell here
        cell?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true    // or reload cell
}
```

Do not forget to set tag to your checkbox in cellForRowAtIndexPath  method like:

```
cell.checkBoxButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

Comment: I got an idea from this..how ever below check worked for me -----------if let secondCell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: (index + 1), section: 0)) as? MyCustomCell {

Comment: @Ashh You are doing it in the hardcoded way. Which will limit you and you have to write more logic if you have to change

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have your own custom `UITableViewCell` class. And your `MyTableViewController` is an delegate for this tableview cell. 
Whenever user check/uncheck, your box delegate tells your controller about it and you invoke reload method to get rid of given row.

That's solution I am using in my app.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    private struct CurrentSetting {
        var RowAEnabled: Bool = true
        var RowBEnabled: Bool = true
        var RowCEnabled: Bool = true
        var RowDEnabled: Bool = true
        var RowEEnabled: Bool = true
        //...
        //maybe more?
    }


    /// Let's say those are your table view rows. Data or whatever.
    fileprivate var settings: [String] {
        //In here you have your static position.
        var configuration = ["Row A","Row B", "Row C"]
        //However, if some data are enabled/disabled you modify it based on settings
        if current.RowAEnabled {
            configuration += ["Row D"]
        }
        return configuration
    }
    //This is your setting for current tableview
    private var current = CurrentSetting()
}

//Use this to reload row for your enable/disable cell.
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
```

Example how did that work with my app.
IMPORTANT: settings it's data source for your tableview. number of items.

[image]

Comment: I will suggest to find more optimised  and generic way

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar you can allay suggest it here

Comment: added new answer below as it's totally different can't edit your's

Answer (score 0):

In action of that checkBox, you can perform `reloadData` of your tableview.
After that, you can check inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

like:

```
if indexpath.row == 4  
then  
//just my opinion, you can do whatever you want.  
cell.userInteractionEnabled = checkBox.isSelected
```

or you can check inside `numberOfRowsInSection`, you can remove it from dataSource.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest the optimised and robust way.

If you have and `Datasource Array` to load in `TableView` then add one extra property named isEnabled in the Object.

Else

create a `Array` as follows

```
var cellStateArray = Array(repeating: true, count: numberOfRows)
```

then when you will toggle the check box depending on that toggle the flag for required cell index (currently it's row 4 for you) to `false` OR `true` in `cellStateArray`

And in the `cellForRowAt` Method check the flag in `cellStateArray` for the respective `cell index` and set userInteractionEnabled enable/disable (extra configuration if you want)

And then simple reload the cell/table

Comment: ok, but let assume the cell enable/disable state determine it presents on a screen. In that case your solution does not help. The data are still there. So only what he can do is changing size to 0 which won't remove view from hierarchy. However. my solution allows to do that.

Comment: I don't think that will be the case just reloading the cell will help to update the state of cell